# Replace java socket client with the socket.io client in angular 2

Tags: java, angular, socket.io

I am currently connecting to a server and a message to server using java client socket, I want to do the same using socket.io in my angular 2 application. I  tried as in the below code but no luck in sending the message, any suggestion. Please help.

JAVA:

```
public String triggerMessage() {
             String ipServer = "localhost";
        int port = 5555;
        String token="";
        try {
            Socket socket= new Socket(ipServer, port);
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOut.writeUTF("[START]");
            BufferedReader resReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String str;
            while ((str = resReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(str.contains("TOKEN")){
                    token = str;
                }
            }
            dataOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        return token;

    }
```

ANGULAR 2 (Socket.io):

below is the service written in angular 2 (typescript) to send the message to the server.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

export class SocketService {
  startDevice(){
  this.socket = io('https://localhost:5555');
  this.socket.emit('message', '[START]');
  }
}
```

Can any one suggest on what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Found that socket.io can be used only for connection between socket.io client and its server. 
[How to connect to a telnet server from node using socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501968/how-to-connect-to-a-telnet-server-from-node-using-socket-io)