# NodeJs - how to use socket.io to send tcp packet to another computer in local area network

Tags: node.js, xml, tcp, socket.io, feathersjs

I have NodeJs web service in based web socket. One of my file by the server side tries send xml to printer in local area network on ip address 192.168.1.5 but this ip is in my physical network not in area network by server side. When I open the web service on localhost it's work but when I open my service via network it's not work. How can I use web socket that nodejs app will send xml via TCP to another localhost in local area network using socket client just like me?

for example (my local area network):

localhost - 192.168.1.100

printer - 192.168.1.5

localhost (my physical computer) -> opening web service (NodeJS) on browser -> running script (service) -> sending xml via TCP to printer (192.168.1.5)

is this scenario possible?

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501968/how-to-connect-to-a-telnet-server-from-node-using-socket-io/24501995#24501995

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use webSocket or socket.io to send a plain TCP packet.  webocket is its own protocol and socket.io runs on top of webSocket.  It initiates a connection with an http request, uses it's own data format framing and its own security scheme.  As such a webSocket client can only connect to a webSocket server or a socket.io client to a socket.io server, not to a plain TCP device.

You can use the `Net` module in node.js to make plain TCP connections.  So, you can contact the printer directly from node.js if that would work.

But, you can't make plain TCP connections directly form a browser web page without using some sort of browser plug-in that has access to native code or without sending some sort of http or webSocket or socket.io request to a server and having the server contact the printer on your behalf (which would require server and printer to be on the same local network).

Comment: Thanks, I used net module in my project but if I want it to work I have to configure port forwarding. I think this is not good solutions because the printer not have any authorization. Can you tell me how can I do this better?

Comment: @SeaDog - What are you trying to do with the printer?  Browsers have their own abilities to print.  Perhaps you can use that.  You create a browser window with the desired content in it and call `window.print()`.

Comment: @friend00 - exactly it is a online fiscal device. This device is in my office while my web app by the which I can prints receipts and other reports is in cloud. I implemented net nodejs module and I try print report on 192.168.1.5 ip address (fiscal printer) but it works only when I run my app on localhost (my physical computer in local area network). I need print documents by my app in cloud but the reports must print in my office on my printer. I think about port forwarding but this device not have any authorization.

Comment: In the end, you will need either a whole in the firewall with port forwarding so you can reach the printer from outside the network or you will need a proxy of some sort that is on the same network as the printer and can broker the transaction or you will need a cloud aware printer that can connect to your app in the cloud. 
 Maybe a cloud print tool could help such as [Google Cloud Print](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2158844/getting-started-with-google-cloud-print.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will have to use a firewall.